# Datastore Admin: Backup to Google Cloud Storage - unsported filesystem, why?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to make datastore backup. I have choosen few tables, added existing bucket name and after clicking Backup Entities I'm receiving this error:

> Unsupported filesystem: mcourser-poland-datastore-bigquery

Where can be a problem? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, we only need to add name of bucket without gs/